# Whiptail/dialog input bug when executed from rc.local

Tags: terminal, systemd, dialog, whiptail

I need to start a Bash script containing calls to dialog at Debian boot time. This is how I've been able to do it:

- Unset default root password
- Set *--autologin* option to tty1 in *initrd* (*1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --autologin root tty1*)
- Write the full path of my script in */etc/rc.local*

However, dialog has an unusual behaviour: the box appears, but then stdin seems to be overflowing stdout. When I press the arrow keys, no button is selected, but instead, corresponding ASCII chars are displayed on top of the dialog box, starting from the default choice position:

[image: display bug in dialog]

Note that if I then press enter, the keys are sent to dialog and corresponding option is selected as intended. The script has been testing working when executed normally.

I suppose something is missing in the shell initialization: if I put `/bin/bash` in `rc.local`, I get `no job control in this shell` message, and can't send signal to processes nor get pids (I get question marks instead of pids in `top`).

Why is this behaviour and how can I overcome it?

Comment: Your terminal seems to be in [cooked mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooked_mode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that any interactive script launched from rc.local will have similar issues with stdin. I found a workaround [on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/588871):

> Just launch your script using `openvt -s -w /path/to/script.sh`

(explanation at the original post)

Answer (score 2):

The console is not connected to `stdin` of the `whiptail` process.

It looks like the same issue as seen in [rc.local with read will not echo key strokes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105640/rc-local-with-read-will-not-echo-key-strokes%20rc.local%20with%20read%20will%20not%20echo%20key%20strokes).

The suggested answer there is to add `plymouth quit` before attempting console input.

Alternatively, it may be possible to arrange for Plymouth itself to display your warning; something like

```
 plymouth pause-progress 
 plymouth message --text="Your system will be hosed.  Is that what you want?  What you really, really want? [yn]" 
 plymouth watch-keystroke --keys="YyNn " --command="tee /tmp/key_pressed"
 case $(cat /tmp/key_pressed) in
     [nN])
         poweroff;          # abort!
         ;;
 esac
 plymouth message --text="Okay, you asked for this" 
 plymouth unpause-progress
```

Caveat: I'm not a Plymouth expert, and haven't tried the above.

Comment: It did not do the trick, plymouth is not installed on my system. However the link you provided helped me find a solution (which I'm going to post next ). Thanks!